# Tokenizing in Python

Tags: python

I have a text file with 32 documents and I will like Python to notice it. Therefore I am searching for a tokenizing process to detect when a new document begins and ends.

[image]

As we can see in the image, each document starts with the combination: Number of 32 DOCUMENTS. In the image I am just showing the heather of the second document. The next document will start with 3 of 32 DOCUMENTS and so on. Can anybody help me to develop a simple code so that Python recognizes that there are 32 articles?

Comment: What have you attempted so far? Please show us your code, and clarify what problem you are having with it. Please add your code and example text directly into your question, rather than posting a screenshot. It makes it easier for others to replicate your problem and help debug.

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer. I have just started learning Python and therefore I do not possess any code for this problem. I am seeking some guidance if possible. Nevertheless I will keep trying and post the code when I have got something. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to go about this:

1. Read the file line by line
2. Check each line if it matches `X of Y documents`.
3. If it does, start a new list that contains that line and add the previous list to your list of documents.
4. If it doesn't, append the line to the list you've started
5. Go to 2., until you've reached the end of the file.

So, for example:

```
import re
sections = []
current = []
with open("myfile.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if re.search(r"(?i)\d+ of \d+ documents", line):
            sections.append("".join(current))
            current = [line]
        else:
            current.append(line)
    if current:
        sections.append("".join(current))
```

Comment: The way I checked it works is by writing print(len(sections)) which gives me 32 as a result. Thanks very much!